# Converting keyboard characters

Tags: linux, keyboard

I'd like to find/write a program that can intercept all characters entered at a keyboard and map Dvorak to QWERTY if a control character is depressed. I would normally type in Dvorak, but as soon as I typed in a control character such as CTRL or ALT my input would switch to Dvorak. For example CTRL-D would become CTRL-E.

The operating system would be Debian. I don't know where to start (maybe xmodmap?) so any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: To clarify: you want Dvorak normally, but QWERTY when a modifier other than Shift (i.e. Ctrl/Alt/Meta/Super/etc.) is held?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://youshottheinvisibleswordsman.co.uk/2008/05/13/dvorak-configuration-debian-linux/) appears to be a good resource